# On evaluating $\rho(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\Gamma(z)P(sz)\,dz.$

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, contour-integration, residue-calculus, analytic-continuation

How do you evaluate the following integral?

> $$\rho(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\Gamma(z)P(sz)\,dz.$$

$P(\cdot)$ is the prime zeta function. I got the integral from taking $\rho(s)=\sum_{\rho\in\Bbb P}\exp\big(-\rho^s\big)$ and using the [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) to extend the domain of $\rho(s)$.

The series $\rho(s)$ converges for $\Re(s)>0.$

By definition:

$$\rho(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\Gamma(z)\sum_{p\in\Bbb P}p^{-sz}\,dz.$$

So I ended up summing up the residues of the integrand at the poles and got:

$$ \rho(s)=\Gamma
\bigg(1+\frac{1}{s}\bigg)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}P(-ns) $$

Is this about right? I think I messed up somewhere.

Comment: *So I ended up summing up the residues...* - nonsense, $\Re s=0$ is the natural boundary for $P(s)$, which then cannot be continued to anywhere to the left of it.

Comment: *The series $\rho(s)$ converges for $\Re s>0$* - false, and you must know it already. It converges only for *real* $s>0$.

Comment: thanks for the constructive feedback, tried my best

Comment: "The series $\rho(s)$ converges..." Isn't this contradictory?

Comment: I mean that if $\Im s\neq 0$ then the series $\rho(s)$ diverges (the term *doesn't tend* to $0$).

Comment: So just to make sure I understand, $\rho(s)$ (the series) can't be analytically continued?

Comment: Well, I don't know, but at least **not this way**.