# Analytic continuation of $p(s)=\sum_{p\text{ prime}} e^{-p^s}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, prime-numbers, analytic-continuation

> What is the analytic continuation of $p(s)=\sum_{p\text{ prime}} e^{-p^s}=e^{-2^s}+e^{-3^s}+e^{-5^s}+\cdots$ ?

I've attempted the case where the index of the sum is not prime, but is $n=1,2,3,\dots$. In this case we can use the Cahen-Mellin integral to get an analytic continuation.

However this technique [doesn't work](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4047660) for $p(s)$.

$p(s)$ converges for real variable $s>0$.

Comment: Do you care of the answers to your questions? Your series converges iff $s > 0$, it is obviously smooth, but it is not obvious at all that it is analytic anywhere.

Metamorphy showed that the main step is for $c > 0$ , $e^{-x}=\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \Gamma(z)x^{-z}dz$.

For $c >1$ and $s > 1$, 
$$\sum_p e^{-p^s}=\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \Gamma(z)\sum_p p^{-zs}dz$$

Comment: Due to the infinitely many singularities of $\sum_p p^{-s}$ in the critical strip we can't extend to $s$ non-real. Due to the natural boundary at $\Re(s)=0$ we won't be able to shift the contour to the left, in contrary to $\sum_{p^k} e^{-p^{sk}} \log p=\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \Gamma(z)\frac{-\zeta'(sz)}{\zeta(sz)}dz$ where the residue theorem has good chances to work.

Comment: "we can't extend s to non-real. we can't shift the contour." what can we do?

Comment: So you don't read the comments neither ?  ;-) I said to replace your function by a closely related one.